# How do I detect an azure blob storage file change and delete local cache instance of that file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, caching

I am currently migrating a legacy .net application from a dedicated server to auzre web app.  The application uses uses System.Web.Cache CacheDependency for XML file caching.

> Caching.CacheDependency(xmlFile) normally detects changes made to the file and updating the cache with the latest version.

The issue is that the files are now being stored in an Azure storage account (ie. not the local file system) and I need a way to detect changes made to the files.  The Caching.CacheDependency(xmlFile) will not work in this case as it looks for a local path.

Since the file based CacheDependency does not detect changes to files on the Azure blob storage, how can we make the web app detect changes and remove the stale cache file from the local cache?

I am thinking that a webfunction with a blob trigger will solve the file monitoring part but how do I remove the file from the System.Cache of the web app?  I am also concerned about excessive resources being consumed.  There are thousands of files.

Has anyone run into this yet and if so, what was your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a issue like that.

The solution was create new Endpoint in WebApp. This endpoint just clean the cache. So we built a WebJob with blob storage trigger, then when this trigger occurs, the webjob call the new endpoint by a POST and the cache read the new datas.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I agree that this would be a workable solution and most likely the only solution:)   The endpoint solves the issue of communicating the file change to the server.  I will implement and see how resource intensive it is.